# Redirect Product page to custom page with image in Magento

Tags: image, magento, magento-1.7

Hi I want to add custom page in my magento store where I can customize product image .

Now When user select the product and then click on proceed button I want to redirect it to my page with product image and product id .. then again after it should forward to cart page.

Can any one have face this issues before .. I am beginner to magento.

Please let me know which files should be updated and which code should be added to my custom page to get that product image with its id, name etc ..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a CMS page where you can add an image? O_O You can just copy the image URL and paste it to the CMS page you want. :D